# Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

My app was working normally since today.I already included Firebase Storage in my Android Flutter App and it works after that today I get AppCheck Errors suddenly. I was not include App Check for our project or not enforced in settings. After that I was following the official documentation for initialization appcheck : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/usage.

This is my Kotlin MainActivity:

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.debug.DebugAppCheckProviderFactory
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
        val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
        firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
                DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance())
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

and this is my main():

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I also added this to my app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:16.0.0-beta01'
}
```

When I make a request to firebase storage, I would expect something like this in my console:

**D DebugAppCheckProvider: Enter this debug secret into the allow list in the Firebase Console for your project: 123a4567-b89c-12d3-e456-789012345678**

Instead, I'm getting an error:

```
2021-11-21 18:11:51.442 2091-3452/com.sekspir.grind4gain W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
2021-11-21 18:11:53.500 2091-3452/com.sekspir.grind4gain W/StorageUtil: Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.
2021-11-21 18:12:11.136 2091-3633/com.sekspir.grind4gain V/NativeCrypto: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xdaa42da8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

Did I miss something here? I am using a real Android device with flutter debug build.

This is Firestore AppCheck Stats looks both of request income
[image: Firestore AppCheck Stats]

But in Storage session there are not any request fail or success.
[image: App Check Storage Stat]

Comment: Could you please confirm that your Android log level is set to `DEBUG` level and above? This is to make sure the `DebugAppCheckProvider: Enter this debug secret into the allow list in the Firebase Console for your project: 123a4567-b89c-12d3-e456-789012345678` logcat entry isn't being filtered out.

Answer (score 2):

Can you double check that you correctly [enabled the enforcement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers#enable-enforcement) ?
It is required to work with Firebase Storage solutions.

Are you using your app in "PWA" mode or in "Native" mode ?
The Recaptcha may be mandatory depending on how your app is distributed.

```
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
  );
```

I'm not sure about your implementation of the `appcheck-debug` dependency on the Android Native side.
Since it's already implemented by the Flutter library itself, you should remove it.

*Personal note : I had troubles with `FirebaseAppCheck` on some devices, while it was working perfectly on other devices.

This library is still in beta and I would recommend to wait before using it in production.*

Answer (score 2):

I get it what your issue might be. I was facing the same problem but in my case the issue was that I changed the application name and application id (com.example.appname) for releasing. But this application id was not updated in Firebase console. So you basically need to update the google-services.json file in your app with the updated application Id.
And for that follow the below steps

1. Create a new app with the updated package name (put your new application id there) in the firebase console.
2. Download the new google-services file(this is the main step) and now copy the content of this new google-services file. Now go back to your android/flutter app and replace the content of old google-services.json file with the content of new google-services.json(that you copied).
3. Now add the SHA keys to your new app in the firebase console.
4. Now rebuild your flutter/android app and it should work.