W/StorageUtil( 9633): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead
I am trying to make a chat app with flutter and firebase,i have a problem with sending images, when i save the image and then try to get it with the getDownloadURL() the app shows many errors i don't understand why.
here is the code for the function that must send the image to the other user:
final FirebaseStorage fireStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

        sendImage({required File file,required String roomId,required String uid})async {
          String ext = file.path.split('.').last;
          final ref = fireStorage
              .ref()
              .child('image/$roomId/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.$ext');

          ref.putFile(file);

          String imageUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
           FireData().sendMessage(uid, imageUrl, roomId,type: 'image');

        }
        }

this is the code for the sendMessage function:
Future sendMessage(String uid, String msg, String roomId, {String? type}) async{
   String msgId = Uuid().v1();
   Message message = Message(
       id: msgId,
       fromId: myUid,
       createdAt: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
       msg: msg,
       read: '',
       toId: uid,
       type: type ?? 'text'
   );
   await firestore.collection('rooms').doc(roomId).collection('messages').doc(msgId).set(message.toJson());
  }

and this is how i call the sendImage function :
IconButton(
                                onPressed: ()async{
                              ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
                              XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(
                                  source: ImageSource.gallery);
                              if(image!=null){
                                FireStorage().sendImage(
                                   file: File(image.path),
                                   roomId: widget.roomId,
                                   uid: widget.chatUser.id!
                               );
                              }
                            }, icon: const Icon(Iconsax.camera)
                            )

this is the error i am getting:
enter image description here
enter image description here
and as u can see here the image is stored in the storage:
enter image description here
i tried to run the app on chrome but it just got worse
please if anyone knows how to solve it
it s driving me crazy

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058262/error-getting-app-check-token-using-placeholder-token-instead

I have faced that problem many times, the only way to solve is to await while putting the file:
   await ref.putFile(file);

it works, but there's something we should focus on:
ref.putFile(), this method returns a value but not in the Future what's the purpose of the await here, isn't it unnecessary!.
it's another question here!, answering it requires to expose the concrete implementaion of putFile method.
Similar question that expose the same problem.
BTW: mark sendMessage method as a void method it dosn't return anything, so remove Future.
void sendMessage(String uid, String msg, String roomId, {String? type}) async{}

Make the same for FireStorage().sendImage if it returns Future, mark it as void.
Hope it helps you.
